# SQL Server - Getting XML from result set within one tag

Tags: sql-server, xml

I am trying without much success to build a `XML` out of my result set.
My result set should look like this :

```
   <CSVRoot>
        <CsvColumn>MDCY_Code</CsvColumn>
        <CsvColumn>MDCY_Description</CsvColumn>
    </CSVRoot>
```

This is what my query returns :

```
<CSVRoot>
  <CSVHeader>
    <CsvColumn>MDCY_Code</CsvColumn>
  </CSVHeader>
  <CSVHeader>
    <CsvColumn>MDCY_Description</CsvColumn>
  </CSVHeader>
</CSVRoot>
```

I know that I can use `flowr` on this formed `XML` and remake the `XML`, but that's additional processing. Is there any way to do this without further processing ( such as using a `flowr` to form a new `XML` ) in one query?

This is what I've used:

select
    utma.CsvColumn as [ColumnName]
from
    Methods m
inner join
    UITestMap utm on m.UITestMapID = utm.ID
inner join
    SubMethods sm on m.Id = sm.HeaderID
inner join
    UITestMapActions utma on sm.UITestMapActionID = utma.ID

for xml path('CSVHeader'),root('CSVRoot')

**Edit 2 :**

This isn't working, I get the same output.Utma has one column that I need in my query and that is CSVColumn.

**Edit 3:**

Now I'm getting this :

```
<CsvHeader>
  <ColumnName>MDCY_Cod</ColumnName>
  <ColumnName>MDCY_Descriere</ColumnName>
</CsvHeader>
```

Which is the correct answer.
I wasn't sure how I wanted to process the result sets, actually I will need to use flowr to create a new xml out of this output. ( which is what I needed in the first place)

Comment: Table structure and data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
    utma.CsvColumn
from
    Methods m
for xml path(''),root('CSVRoot')
```